# How to get format off cell in excel by c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, format

Is it possible to get particularly format of cell in excel?
I'm trying to read type of `value(string,numeric,currency,date,time)`. I only can read string or numeric but it isn't enough for me. Important thing is i want to read excel cell format, not actual cell's value format.

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library.

Comment: Can you include an example of the code you're currently using?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with **OfficeOpenXml** library. I think this is a close solution for you.

```
switch(worksheet.Cells[i, j].Style.Numberformat.Format) {
case "#": //numeric (int)
    break;
case "€#,##0.00":  //currency
    break;
case "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm":  //datetime
    break; }
```